# How to redirect to another page if page is visited, but not if page is included (PHP)

Tags: php, redirect, include

I am kind of a PHP-newbie and tried to learn by myself, but now I stumbled over a problem.

I have an index.php, which does something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php include("header.php"); ?>

<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php printHeader(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a header.php, which looks like this:

```
<?php function printHeader(){ ?>
    <p>foo</p>
<?php } ?>
}
```

Now, my problem is, when I access index.php, it works fine, but if I access header.php, I want to redirect to index.php instead of seeing a blank page. If I use header(..):

```
<?php header("Location: index.php") ?>
<?php function printHeader(){ ?>
    <p>foo</p>
<?php } ?>
}
```

I get of course an Error ("The page isn't redirecting properly") because index.php redirects to itself which starts a loop.

Is there any kind of main function in PHP, which only gets called when the page is called directly and not when its only included? Or is there any other solution?

Thank you in advance! :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  redirection to occur ONLY if the script is directly accessed, you may use the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`  to determine.

So for the header, please change from

```
<?php header("Location: index.php") ?>
<?php function printHeader(){ ?>
    <p>foo<?/p>
<?php } ?>
}
```

to

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="header.php" || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="/header.php") {
header("Location: index.php") ;
}
?><?php function printHeader(){ ?>
    <p>foo<?/p>
<?php } ?>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <?php require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/header.php'; ?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php printHeader(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

header.php

```
<?php
/* -------------------- */
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/header.php' ) {
    /* -------------------- */
    header('Location: ./');
}
/* -------------------- */
function printHeader () {
    /* -------------------- */
    echo '<p>foo</p>';
}
?>
```